# Finding $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2}))}{\sin(\sin(x))} $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

I have the following solution, only the first equality of which bothers me:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \cos^{2}(\frac{x}{2}))}{\sin(\sin(x))}  =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin(\pi \sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2}))}{\sin(\sin(x))}  =\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\pi \frac{\sin(\frac{x}{2})}{2\cos(\frac{x}{2})}.\frac{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\sin(2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2}))}.\frac{\sin(\pi \sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2}))}{\pi \sin^{2}(\frac{x}{2})}\
> \
> =0$

What is the justification for replacing $\cos^{2}$ with $\sin^{2}$?

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\cos^{2}(x)=1-\sin^{2}(x)$, so $\sin(\pi\cos^{2}(x))=\sin(\pi-\pi\sin^{2}(x))=\sin(\pi \sin^{2}(x))$, since $\sin(\pi-y)=\sin(y)$.